# Print formatted source from Delphi 2010 IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How to print formatted Delphi source on a printer?

Comment: Hmmm, how about: open source file in IDE, format it (manually or using Ctrl-D in D2010+), print it (File|Print)?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Thanks. I was looking for it in Edit menu and Ctrl+P does not work from IDE. Thanks again.

Comment: You mean print, like in transfer usable, navigable code from the IDE onto "dead trees"???? Why? This is not necessary the "I'm green so I don't print" talk, I'm simply curious, why would you want to PRINT code? I find printed code awful, a pain to read;

Comment: @Cosmin, I've occasionally found it useful in a code review, either to allow viewing several pages at once, or to allow marking it up with a pen. It can also be helpful it you're giving a presentation and want to provide hand-outs for people to refer to while you talk.

Comment: @Marjan: you should make this an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @Cosmin I often print code and read it in a quiet room with a marker pen.

Comment: @Uwe: thanks, and done. @Cosmin: printing can be usefull when you are working with a smaller size monitor and can't view to sets of source side by side to compare, or to incorporate parts of one in the other...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested, here is my comment as an answer:

To print formatted source code from the Delphi IDE:

- Open the source file in IDE,
- format it (manually or using Ctrl-D in D2010+),
- print it (File|Print)

Answer (score 0):

Once, when I had to take over a legacy red-headed stepchild project that had always gotten the left over efforts of programmers ordered to work on it, I did a lot of analysis of the code flow and logic using Microsoft Word.  I copied the code out of the environment (it was in VB, but the same thing would work in Delphi), pasted it into Word in a mono-spaced type and added comments using text boxes, etc.  In the comments, I could condense some obscure sequences into pseudo-code or summarize the requirements and effects of code blocks or do anything else that made the code more understandable to me.  There were a few times when I needed to discuss the code with others and at that point I could email or sometimes even print my attempts at making sense from some pretty unruly code.

Although this is a reason why I might print some code, I would probably not do it directly from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from your own software, you can use SynEdit.

It highlights code in a TMemo-like component, and you can print that.  It's free and doesn't require external dll's or anything.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/synedit/